# Why is pytest giving an error that collectors cannot be found?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytest

Trying to implement pytest into a QA script I wrote in a Jupyter Notebook on VS Code. Never used pytest before so I'm picking up a lot of new jargon.

I've installed pytest, installed python and added to PATH, imported pytest into the same notebook where my code and data are located and have written the following code towards the end of the notebook:

```
#TEST 1
def test_1():
    assert test_1_incorrect_rows.empty

#TEST 2
def test_2():
    assert test_2_incorrect_rows.empty

#TEST 3
def test_3():
    assert test_3_incorrect_rows.empty

#TEST 4
def test_4():
    assert test_4_incorrect_rows.empty

#TEST 5
def test_5():
    assert test_5_incorrect_rows.empty

!pytest test_QA.ipynb
```

I am asserting that the dataframes that are called incorrect rows are empty, and if this is true then QA has passed for that test. Every time I run all I get the following output:

```
==================================== test session starts ==========================
platform win32 -- Python 3.12.0, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: C:\Users\Myself
collected 0 items

===================================== no tests ran in 0.01s ========================
ERROR: found no collectors for c:\Users\Myself\...\test_QA.ipynb
```

At this point I really don't know what could be the reason that these tests are not being collected, my knowledge in pytest is very limited.

I would've expected that these 5 tests would've been collected, especially with the amount of troubleshooting that I've gone through for this to work.